# epoll_wait on several Threads faster?

Tags: multithreading, epoll

I am thinking of programming a tcp server based on `epoll`. 
To achieve the best performance i want to implement multi core support too. But during my researches the following question came up:
Is it faster to call two `epoll_wait()`-Calls from two different threads, each observing their own file descriptors on a dual core? Or is this as fast as calling just one single `epoll_wait()` which observes all file descriptors?

Since the Kernel observes the file descriptors, i think it doens't matter how much threads i use on user space calling `epoll_wait()`?

Comment: How often do you expect changes to occur?

Answer (score 20):

You can even call epoll_wait concurrently on multiple threads for the same epoll_fd as long as you use edge-triggered (EPOLLET) mode (and be careful about synchronisation). Using that approach you can get real performance benefits on multi-core machines compared to a single-threaded epoll event loop.

I have actually done performance measurements some time ago, see my blog postings for the results:

- http://cmeerw.org/blog/748.html#748
- http://cmeerw.org/blog/746.html#746

Comment: Why only with EPOLLET mode?

Comment: Because if you work in any other mode, then the epoll will report the same file descriptors to several threads, causing spurious wake ups.

Comment: This link (https://idea.popcount.org/2017-02-20-epoll-is-fundamentally-broken-12/) can help with understanding the "spurious wake ups" which the link refers to as thundering herd.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you're correct that the performance of epoll per se is no different in the two scenarios you mention. What could make a difference, OTOH, is that by having an event loop in each thread you don't need to context switch to a separate worker thread to handle the connection. This is e.g. how nginx works, see e.g. http://www.aosabook.org/en/nginx.html .